# How to show blank if no search results found through Ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to search similar posts through Ajax while typing in input. And I want to get the blank div if there are no results.
Here is my Ajax code I have tried:

```
$('#title').on('keyup',function(){
   $value=$(this).val();
       $.ajax({
          type : 'get',
          url : '{{URL::to('similarpost')}}',
          data:{'search':$value},
          success:function(data){
             if(data != null){
                 $('.mydiv').html(data);
             }
             else{
                 $('.mydiv').html(); //Here I want the div to be blank but it's not working
             }
          }
       });
 })
```

Comment: Try : `$('.mydiv').html("");` this will empty div.

Comment: Thank you.. But it doesn't work for me. The problem is when I clear the input it displays all the posts

Comment: Add one extra condition : `if($value != " "){//your ajax code here}else{  $('.mydiv').html("");}`

Answer (score 0):

try like this, if you want the div to be blank, put like this `$('.mydiv').html('');`

```
$('#title').on('keyup',function(){
   let $value = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
          type : 'get',
          url : '{{URL::to('similarpost')}}',
          data:{'search':$value},
          success:function(data){
             if(data != null){
                 $('.mydiv').html(data);
             }else{
                 $('.mydiv').html('');
             }
          }
       });
 })
```